# How to Load a pre-trained model into Keras without the Weight and bias?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pre-trained-model

I need to Load a pre-trained model into `Keras` without the Weight and bias. I
also just want to use the Architecture of the model alone for my training.

Example: 
I want to load `coco_mobilenet` model pre-trained without Weights and bias.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
net=keras.applications.MobileNet(weight=None)
net.summary()
```

view [keras mobilenet api](https://keras.io/applications/#mobilenet) for detail